# is this still vulnerable to sql attacks? can you see any problems?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, validation

Hey been fiddling with this all night just wondering if anyone can notice any flaws with my code? I was told before I was using out of date sql connection strings so I've updated. feedback would be great!

```
 <?php
    if ( empty( $_POST ) ){
    ?>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Full Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sub_name" />
        <br>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sub_email" />

            <div class="pull-right">
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>

    <?php
    } else {

    try {


    $db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $subsc_username, $subsc_password );

    $form = $_POST;
    $subsc_name = $form[ 'sub_name' ];
    $subsc_email = $form[ 'sub_email' ];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO subscribers ( 
        subsc_name, subsc_email ) 
        VALUES ( 
        $subsc_name, $subsc_email )";

    $query = $db->prepare( $sql );
    $query->execute( array( 'subsc_name'=>$subsc_name, 'subsc_email'=>$subsc_email, ) );

    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: read ircmaxell's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection/12202218#12202218

Comment: It does not look good... this is not how you prepare/bind variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using placeholders in your prepared statement. The correct usage is:

```
<?php
// $_POST might be empty even if the request is a POST
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $subsc_username, $subsc_password);
        // default error mode is to return FALSE
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    $subsc_name = $_POST['sub_name'];
    $subsc_email = $_POST['sub_email'];

    // never put variables directly in your SQL queries
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO subscribers (subsc_name, subsc_email) VALUES (:subsc_name, :subsc_email)';

    try {
        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(
            ':subsc_name'  => $subsc_name,
            ':subsc_email' => $subsc_email,
        ));
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
} else {
    echo <<<EOF
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Full Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sub_name" />

            <br>

            <label>Email:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sub_email" />

            <div class="pull-right">
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
EOF;
}
?>
```

Comment: really apreciate this working example alessandro!

Comment: Alessandro what would be the best way to add some basic validation/success messaging to this? would i need to use jquery?

Comment: If you want to perform live validation you can use some jQuery plugin, but it can easily be disabled so you *have* to validate on the server as well.

Comment: sure, can these messages which are happening at the moment be made a bit more user friendly? so instead of saying: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'user@email.com' for key 'subsc_email' it could say "sorry you are already subscribed to this mailing list" ?
thannks

Comment: Unless you want to parse the exception's message, I suggest you perform a SELECT query on the ```subscribers``` table. If the query returns a row, then the user is already subscribed.

Comment: could i not catch exceptions like duplicates? for example:
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    # 23000 error code means the key already exists, so UPDATE!   
    if($e->getCode() == 23000) {  
        echo 'User is already subscribed';

} else {
    echo <<<EOF

Comment: I guess you could! :)

Answer (score 1):

You try to bind values in the `execute()`, but insert the variables directly.

And you got a useless `,` at the end of your array.

Also you should be sure that you're not using emulated statements.

You should it change to this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO subscribers ( 
        subsc_name, subsc_email ) 
        VALUES ( 
        :subsc_name, :subsc_email )";
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array( ':subsc_name'=>$subsc_name, ':subsc_email'=>$subsc_email ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You have no prepare template, you just have ready-to-go query in $sql with non-escaped values.

Answer (score 0):

If you check this line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO subscribers ( 
    subsc_name, subsc_email ) 
    VALUES ( 
    $subsc_name, $subsc_email )";
```

Try to understand what you are doing. You are using double qoutes, which means variables are actually parsed. So this line already evaluates to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO subscribers ( 
    subsc_name, subsc_email ) 
    VALUES ( 
    VALUE_OF_$subsc_name, VALUE_OF_subsc_email )";
```

So yes, it is vulnerable to SQL injection. 
If you would use single quotes then the line would stay as the first version, but then its still not how PDO works. Check [this site](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) for examples on how to use it.

Comment: thanks for your pointers Hugo :) apreciated!